# CPAN install Device::USB Not OK

Tags: perl, usb, cpan, libusb, usb-drive

I'm on Debian 8 and I've got error when I Try to install Device::USB module with cpan

```
cpan  Device::USB 
Reading '/home/system/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Thu, 25 Aug 2016 14:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Device::USB'
Checksum for /home/system/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GW/GWADEJ/Device-USB-0.36.tar.gz ok
Configuring G/GW/GWADEJ/Device-USB-0.36.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Device::USB
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Failed to find module path for 'dump_usb.pl' at Makefile.PL line 50.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
GWADEJ/Device-USB-0.36.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
```

I Checked the FAQ in the dump_usb.pl page in the cpan.org web site and I didn't find any relevant information about this snake biting its tail problem, as the cpan should install dump_usb.pl and its showing it didn't find the module

Thanks for any  help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue which has been reported to [GitHub repo of Device::USB](https://github.com/gwadej/perl-device-usb/issues/2).

Possible solutions as per disucssion on that thread are:

1. Downgrade Inline::MakeMaker
2. [Apply patch suggested by devsaurus](https://github.com/devsaurus/perl-device-usb/commit/4da24648a1f46c84ae45e7bcfcd425bc961ba1ad)

i.e.

Make below change in Makefile.PL

```
+sub MY::libscan {
+   return if ($_[1] eq 'USB.pm' or $_[1] eq 'dump_usb.pl');
+   return $_[1];
+}
```

Comment: Could you tell me which Makefile.PL file  I've to modify ? However I solved the problem installing the package libdevice-usb-perl Thanks for you help

Comment: You could use the repo with fix. Use [this link](https://github.com/devsaurus/perl-device-usb) and follow install instructions from there.

Comment: In short, download ZIP from there. Run following commands `perl Makefile.PL`, `make`, `make test`, `make install`.